# When is sessionReachabilityDidChange(_:) called on a watch WCSessionDelegate?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

Apple's documentation says this in the discussion section of the method [description](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsessiondelegate/1615662-sessionreachabilitydidchange):

> This method is called to let the
>   current process know that its counterpart session’s reachability
>   changed.
>
> The description of the isReachable [property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615683-isreachable) says this: WatchKit
>   extension. The iOS device is within range, so communication can occur
>   and the WatchKit extension is running in the foreground, or is running
>   with a high priority in the background (for example, during a workout
>   session or when a complication is loading its initial timeline data).

I am assuming this would mean that if the watch moves out of or into range of the iOS device, the WatchKit extension would be launched and the WCSessionDelegate's `sessionReachabilityDidChange()` method would be called, and the WCSession's isReachable would be true if the iOS device just came into range and false if it just when out of range.

I have not found a way to verify this in xcode.  For example I put a log message in `sessionReachabilityDidChange(_:)` and walked out of range, but xcode simply says the app lost connection with the iphone and can no longer debug it. Can someone verify this or point me to some documentation that better describes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot verify this in Xcode.
I have an app on iOS and watchOS. To check this kind of situation, I can enable debug alerts on iOS and watchOS. When `func sessionReachabilityDidChange(session: WCSession)` is triggered, I display a debug alert.
Now, if I run  (not under Xcode) my watch extension, and then switch off the paired iPhone, the debug alert is shown on the watch.
This shows that `sessionReachabilityDidChange` is actually called as expected.
Apparently, under Xcode a connected iOS device is always reachable.

**EDIT:**

To check the situation when the watch extension is not in foreground, I did the following:

Instead of showing a debug alert, I set now the complication to a unique value that is not possible otherwise. I launched the watch extension and put it into background by showing the watch face with the complication.
When I now switch off the iPhone, the complication is **not** updated.
This indicates to me that `sessionReachabilityDidChange` is **not** called in background.

Comment: This is a good idea.  Since in the end I really need to make a post to my server whenever these events happen,  I added code to do that.  Unfortunately I only see the posts if the WatchKit app is in the foreground.  Since the alert needs a view controller to present it I suspect thats the behavior you see as well, ie if the app is not in the foreground, you do not see the alert?

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question carefully enough. I will try to check what happens if the watch app is not in the foreground...

Comment: Did you see my edit? Could you verify the behavior of `sessionReachabilityDidChange`?

Comment: Yes that seems to confirm what I am seeing as well.